# Is there a way to automatically download and set up a Bluemix Liberty Profile instance?

Tags: maven, cloud-foundry, websphere-liberty, ibm-cloud

Let's say that I want to configure a Development environment locally that allows me to test my code changes in the same J2EE Container that is also in the Cloud, I know I can easily download and deploy my app to Liberty Profile by following these steps: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/, but I was wondering if I can do the same (download, install and deploy my app in the most possibly automated way) with the Cloud Foundry CLI tool available in Bluemix.

*Similar to Google Cloud Platform, where I can use the Google SDK to download and run a local instance of the Google Application Engine (mvn appengine:devserver) and then, when I'm satisfied with my changes I can just push it to the cloud (mvn appengine:update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deploy your application on a Docker container instead of using Cloud Foundry, you can download the 'ibmliberty' container image. This will enable you to test in your local development environment using the IBM Java Liberty runtime used in the cloud.

Comment: Docker is in Beta mode at the moment, but I get what you're saying, once it's available it will be a very interesting option, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no separate Liberty installation to mimic Bluemix environment. But the core runtime is the same. Download Liberty from wasdev.net and then match your server.xml as shown here:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#starters/liberty/index.html#liberty

Comment: You can utilize Docker containers as well as the liberty build pack to mimic the staging process that CloudFoundry uses. I've used this method successfully for several projects.